# Unable to kill MDCrashReportTool process via AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, ventura

A long-standing bug in Mac OS X causes syncing of iDevices. You have to kill the MDCrashReportTool process to continue syncing.

I made an Automator app to run a short AppleScript to do this. However, while the script can kill other processes, it won't kill MDCrashReportTool.

Can anyone suggest a reason, and a fix, for this?

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    try
        do shell script "pkill 'MDCrashReportTool'" user name "myAdminId" password "MyPassword" with administrator privileges
        
    end try
    
    return
    
    return input
    
end run
```

I used "pkill" instead of "kill" or "killall" because MDCrashReportTool’s PID changes.

I realise that including my password in the script is not good practice. Once the script is killing what it should, I'll change it to a more secure method.

Thanks.

Comment: If `kill` doesn't work, you can always try `kill -9`.

Comment: Does “–9” work with the pkill command?

Comment: `man pkill` :-) Yes, it does